# vba code to select symbols from drop down list

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I'm new here and need some advice for my module. I've created a simple Module to scrapping data.

The specific value is nested within this elements:

```
<button class="dropdown-toggle control-button review-control-button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="icon-star-empty icon-large"></i>
    <span data-bind="text: rating() === 'all' ? 'All Ratings' : rating() + ' Star'">All Ratings</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<div class="arrow">
    ::before
</div>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: 0px;">
    <li>
        <a class="selected-filter-option" href="#" data-bind="css: { 'selected-filter-option': rating() === 'all' }, click: function() { rating('all') }, sense: ['App Intel - Review History - Ratings Filter Change', { 'Filter Selected': 'All Ratings' }]">All Ratings</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-bind="css: { 'selected-filter-option': rating() === 5 }, click: function() { rating(5) }, sense: ['App Intel - Review History - Ratings Filter Change', { 'Filter Selected': '5 Stars' }]">
            5 Star
            <span class="review-star-symbol">★★★★★</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

I just need code to click reviews of 5 Star ★★★★★ 

Here is my module:

```
Sub TestApp()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://sensortower.com/android/id/miniclip-com/app/8-ball-pool/com.miniclip.eightballpool/#review-history?reviews"
    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End With

IE.document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-toggle control-button review-control-button")(0).Click
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:2"))

Dim starsym
For Each starsym In IE.document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-menu")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(1) 
    If starsym.innerText = "5 Star" Then
    starsym.Click
    End If
    Next starsym

End Sub
```

the images drop down list look like this:
[dropdown list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIaEY.jpg)

What did I not do for the code to do what it should?

Comment: Thank you Carsten, seem i've done with the module. i'm using "IHTMLElement" with list of the table element.